# Autosys - Shell script return value -1

Tags: ca, autosys

We scheduled the job from Autosys . From the Job , it is executing shell script and returing below output

```
exit value
Success -0 
Failure - -1
Error - 1
```

Can i use the below command from autosys command part , like this
commad : s(job1,0) or s(job1,-1)  - will it throw any fault alarm.

Comment: the problem is not clear.

do you want to suppress the job failure incase exit codes are 0 and -1.

or do you want to trigger a dependent job based on the exit codes of job1

Comment: yes.. based on value, we need to execute different jo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If there is a need to mark job1 as success when exit code is 1, we can update the job1 JIL as:

```
max_exit_success:1
```

For all job exit less than the number defined, the job would be marked as Success. Max limit is 127.

Now coming to trigger dependent job based on the exit code of job1. Consider the second job as Job1A.

Job1A JIL:

```
condition: exitcode (job1) = 1
```